# Get list of all url images in a folder with AJAX / Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, url, src

I have a folder with images. I would like to retrieve all "urls" of these images to create "img tags" with the corresponding "src", and place them in a "div". How can I do this with AJAX/Jquery ?

```
// What I have :

myFolder |
         | - image_01.jpg
         | - image_02.jpg
         | - image_03.jpg
         | - ...


 // What I want :

<div id="myDiv">
   <img src="http://www.example.com/myFolder/image_01.jpg" />
   <img src="http://www.example.com/myFolder/image_02.jpg" />
   <img src="http://www.example.com/myFolder/image_03.jpg" />
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a master list of url's or are you going to query the folder, then get the urls?

Comment: Look for PHP [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to retrieve a specific folder content.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a way to use jQuery to simply query the filesystem on a server.  You're either going to have to manually maintain an array of the image names in your UI code and use them to build your markup, or you'll need some sort of server-side code to generate the markup or a service to return the image list.  Someone _could_ prove me wrong on this, but I don't think so.

Comment: can only read a directory contents with server side code...and make ajax request to get data

Comment: If the list of images is scrapeable, you can do this with my answer, other way, you can't access the server file system with AJAX / jQuery

Comment: @Tim Roberts : no, I want to query the folder.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette : I suspected a bit of that, but I wanted to avoid the PHP ... :-)

Comment: @anied : ok ... :-)

Comment: @charlietfl : so, PHP..

Comment: @JCHernandez : I'll watch your answer…

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    function lpadZeros(str, max) {
        str = str.toString();
        return str.length < max ? lpadZeros("0" + str, max) : str;
    }
    for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
        var imgObj = $('<img/>');
        imgObj.load(function() {
            var thisimg = this;
            $('#myDiv').append(thisimg);
        });
        imgObj.attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/myFolder/image_' + lpadZeros(i, 2) + '.jpg');
    }
});
```

Comment: Very nice answer, but alas, I don't know the names of the image files! I wrote "image_01.jpg" just for the example, but it might be "holidays_145_75.jpg" or "DSC_0152458.jpg" or anything else. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you know the image list from server side, you need to put them in an array then loop through it.